# Copy image from url to folder goes wrong? - PHP

Tags: php, image, copy

I have a select box with some urls in it (dynamic). I want to upload/copy those images to a folder (with 0777 permission). Somehow it does nothing. Not getting any errors but the images aren't being copied. Whats wrong with my code?

```
echo '<select name="photoselect[]" multiple="multiple"></select>';

echo '<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" name="CopyImages"/> </form>';

$target_dir = "upload/"

if(isset($_POST['CopyImages']))

foreach ($_GET['photoselect'] as $photourl) {
    $photoname= basename($photourl);

    copy($photourl, $target_dir.'/'.$photoname);

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that your `select` menu is not inside your `form`?

Comment: Your form is submitting post request so change `$_GET['photoselect']` to `$_POST['photoselect']`. Also put `select` in `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you form in this way:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="photoselect[]" multiple="multiple"></select>
    <input type="submit" name="CopyImages"/>
</form>
```

And your php code:

```
$target_dir = "upload/";

if(isset($_POST['CopyImages']))
    foreach ($_POST['photoselect'] as $photourl) {
        $photoname= basename($photourl);
        copy($photourl, $target_dir.'/'.$photoname);
    }
}
```